Issue with JDBC_PING after I updated keycloak version from 19 to 25
I'm using JDBC-PING discovery for distributed caching in my Keycloak container in AWS ECS. Recently I have updated the Keycloak version from 19 to 25. All the things are working perfectly, except for the caching. I'm getting the following error.

Records are added to the JGROUPSPING table without any issue.
Following are some additional log messages

My Infinispan configuration looks as follows
<infinispan
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:15.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-15.0.xsd"
      xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:15.0">

  <!-- custom stack goes into the jgroups element -->
  <jgroups>
    <stack name="jdbc-ping-tcp" extends="tcp">
      <JDBC_PING connection_driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
                 connection_username="${env.KC_DB_USERNAME}" connection_password="${env.KC_DB_PASSWORD}"
                 connection_url="jdbc:postgresql://${env.KC_DB_URL_HOST}/${env.KC_DB_URL_DATABASE}"
                 initialize_sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS JGROUPSPING (own_addr varchar(200) NOT NULL, cluster_name varchar(200) NOT NULL, ping_data BYTEA, constraint PK_JGROUPSPING PRIMARY KEY (own_addr, cluster_name));"
                 info_writer_sleep_time="500"
                 remove_all_data_on_view_change="true"
                 stack.combine="REPLACE"
                 stack.position="MPING" />
    </stack>
  </jgroups>
  
  <cache-container name="keycloak">
    <!-- custom stack must be referenced by name in the stack attribute of the transport element -->
    <transport lock-timeout="60000" stack="jdbc-ping-tcp"/>
    <local-cache name="realms" simple-cache="true">
      <encoding>
        <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
        <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
      </encoding>
      <memory max-count="10000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <local-cache name="users" simple-cache="true">
      <encoding>
        <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
        <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
      </encoding>
      <memory max-count="10000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <distributed-cache name="sessions" owners="2">
      <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
    </distributed-cache>
    <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions" owners="2">
      <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
    </distributed-cache>
    <distributed-cache name="offlineSessions" owners="2">
      <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
    </distributed-cache>
    <distributed-cache name="clientSessions" owners="2">
      <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
    </distributed-cache>
    <distributed-cache name="offlineClientSessions" owners="2">
      <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
    </distributed-cache>
    <distributed-cache name="loginFailures" owners="2">
      <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
    </distributed-cache>
    <local-cache name="authorization">
      <encoding>
        <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
        <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
      </encoding>
      <memory max-count="10000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <replicated-cache name="work">
      <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
    </replicated-cache>
    <local-cache name="keys">
      <encoding>
        <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
        <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
      </encoding>
      <expiration max-idle="3600000"/>
      <memory max-count="1000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <distributed-cache name="actionTokens" owners="2">
      <encoding>
        <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
        <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
      </encoding>
      <expiration max-idle="-1" lifespan="-1" interval="300000"/>
      <memory max-count="-1"/>
    </distributed-cache>
  </cache-container>
</infinispan>```


Changing the JDBC configuration as follows resolved the problem
<JDBC_PING connection_driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
                 connection_username="${env.KC_DB_USERNAME}" connection_password="${env.KC_DB_PASSWORD}"
                 connection_url="jdbc:postgresql://${env.KC_DB_URL_HOST}/${env.KC_DB_URL_DATABASE}"
                 initialize_sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS JGROUPSPING (own_addr varchar(200) NOT NULL, cluster_name varchar(200) NOT NULL, bind_addr varchar(200) NOT NULL, updated timestamp default current_timestamp, ping_data BYTEA, constraint PK_JGROUPSPING PRIMARY KEY (own_addr, cluster_name));"
                 insert_single_sql="INSERT INTO JGROUPSPING (own_addr, cluster_name, bind_addr, updated, ping_data) values (?, ?, '${env.JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_EXTERNAL_IP:127.0.0.1}', NOW(), ?);"
                 delete_single_sql="DELETE FROM JGROUPSPING WHERE own_addr=? AND cluster_name=?;"
                 select_all_pingdata_sql="SELECT ping_data, own_addr, cluster_name FROM JGROUPSPING WHERE cluster_name=?"
                 info_writer_sleep_time="500"
                 remove_all_data_on_view_change="true"
                 stack.combine="REPLACE"
                 stack.position="MPING" />

